# Upload throttling in IIS 7

Tags: iis, iis-7, bandwidth, upload, bandwidth-control

I've got a situation where multiple concurrent file uploads are being executed in a web application. These uploads are of massive files, among several users, and it's choking the system into terrible latency issues.

What is the best way for me to solve this problem? Preliminary searches suggest Bandwidth/Bit throttling. Do you agree this is the best solution? And, if so, what's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Bandwidth throttling definitely sounds like the way to go. I would look into whatever firewall is residing in front of your web application to see if it has some kind of QoS functionality built in.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm limited to using network firewalls, which I don't believe hold that functionality. Are you aware of a way IIS can do this? Perhaps a module?